# Elasticsearch : set up parent/child using jdbc-rivers

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, parent-child, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am reading data from Sql Server database/table using jdbc-river currently. As of now I have created a individual type for each of the table in my database. As next step in my implementation I would like to use parent/child types so that I can translate the relationship between my sql tables and store them.

```
Table1
Col_id| name| prop1|prop2|prop3

child_table1
col_id| table_id| child_prop1|child_prop2|child_prop3


curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/parent/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select * from table1",
        "index" : "index1",
        "type" : "parent"
    }
}'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/child/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select * from child_table1",
        "index" : "index1",
        "type" : "child"
    }
}'



curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_river/child/_mapping' -d '{
  "child":{
    "_parent": {"type": "parent"}
  }
}'
```

I would like to store my data in the following format

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "A leading wordsmith",
  "prop1": "data",
  "prop2": "data",
  "prop3": "data",

  "child": [
    {
      "child_prop1": "data",
      "child_prop2": "data",
      "child_prop3": "data",
    }
    {
      "child_prop1": "data1",
      "child_prop2": "data1",
      "child_prop3": "data1",
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone comment on how can I use jdbc-rivers to store my data as parent/child type for above scenario.

**UPDATE**
Based on feedback following is the updated mapping & meta.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/library' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "person": {
      "properties": {
        "person_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "work": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "person"
      },
      "properties": {
        "person_id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "genre": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "publisher": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/person/_meta -d '{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=blogcontext",
    "user": "sa",
    "password": "password",
    "sql": "select person_id as _id, name from person",
    "poll": "30s"
  },
  "index": {
    "index": "library",
    "type": "person",
    "bulk_size": 500,
    "autocommit": true
  }
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/work/_meta -d '{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=blogcontext",
    "user": "sa",
    "password": "password",
    "sql": "select person_id as _parent,name,genre,publisher from work",
    "poll": "30s"
  },
  "index": {
    "index": "library",
    "type": "work",
    "bulk_size": 500,
    "autocommit": true
  }
}'
```

Log file

```
   [2014-01-14 07:10:35,488][ERROR][OneShotRiverMouth        ] bulk [1] error
    org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException: Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.process(IndexRequest.java:597)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.executeBulk(TransportBulkAction.java:165)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:140)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.execute(NodeClient.java:92)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.bulk(AbstractClient.java:149)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.execute(BulkProcessor.java:283)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor.access$400(BulkProcessor.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor$Flush.run(BulkProcessor.java:336)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

thanks

Comment: This is also useful to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assumed that your tables look like:

```
table1
table_id| name| prop1|prop2|prop3

child_table1
child_id| table_id| child_prop1|child_prop2|child_prop3
```

You will need to select your primary row id and named it as "_id", your parent id and named it as "_parent"

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/parent/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select table_id as _id, name, prop1, prop2, prop3 from table1",
        "index" : "index1",
        "type" : "parent"
    }
}'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/child/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select child_id as _id, table_id as _parent, child_prop1, child_prop2, child_prop3 from child_table1",
        "index" : "index1",
        "type" : "child"
    }
}'
```

And define the mapping parent/child as you did, then it's done. You can use parent/child queries to query the parent/child data now.

`UPDATE:`
I already use your newest mapping and create a sample database to import data. Everything work fine, I can index parent/child without any errors. 
I'm using ES 0.9.5, jdbc-river 2.2.2.

Comment: I had tried that but get the following error                     [2014-01-10 07:52:18,112][ERROR][SimpleRiverMouth         ] bulk [5037] error
org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException: Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured

Comment: I think there're something missing in your parent/child mapping. Can you post your mapping on gist ?

Comment: can you post your mapping also ? You need to define parent/child in your mapping in order to use _parent field. Also if possible, let specify the _id field for 2nd river `select person_id as _parent,name,genre,publisher from work`

Comment: I think you misunderstand between the index mappings & river. It's totally difference, you're defining mapping in _river, which is meaningless. You need to define mapping for your index, _river is just another flow to import data into your index. I added some comments in your gist, let test it first

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working. SO I first defined the index mappings & then the meta  for _river(person) & then _river(work).        I get the following error on console once I run the meta for _river(work).              org.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException: Can't specify parent if
 no parent field has been configured                                        https://gist.github.com/jpoth/8406466

Comment: The parent field in your SQL must be named `"_parent", not "parent"`, same for id: `"_id", not "id"`

Comment: is it OK now ? btw, what's your ES & JDBC river version you're using?

Comment: Just notice that your creating river command is wrong, it should be:`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/person/meta`, `_river` is the correct endpoint, NOT `river`. You also need to delete the rivers first before creating your 2 new river `curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/_river/" `